# show that a function is decreasing

Tags: calculus, derivatives

let $f(x)=xa^{\frac{1}{x}}-x$ for positive $x,a\in \mathbb{R}$

Show that $f(x)$ is decreasing on $(0, \infty)$.

I am trying to show that $f'(x)= a^{\frac{1}{x}}(1-\frac{ln(a)}{x})-1$ is always negative.

To do that, I am thinking about showing that finding a max/min for $f'(x)$ by solving for $f''(x) = 0$ then prove that what we found was indeed a maximum by calculating $f'''(x)$ but then things get ugly.

So I'm wondering if there is a easier way.